# How to find only last row from second table, along with its first table row

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables.
**journals** and **volumes**. 
Journal Table has unique rows, and volumes table have rows  based on journal table id, name is journal_id(may be multiple).

**journals table is:**

```
id | journal_name

1  | journal1
2  | journal2
```

**volumes table is:**

```
id | journal_id | volume_name

1  |    1       |  volume1
2  |    1       |  volume2
3  |    1       |  volume3
4  |    2       |  volume4
5  |    2       |  volume5
```

Now I need join with row from journal table and **only last rows of volumes based on journal_id**.

**Result should be:**

```
id | journal_name | journal_id | volume_name

1  | journal1     |   1        |   volume3
2  | journal2     |   2        |   volume5
```

**Not all the rows from volumes table. (Need only last rows from each group of journal_id).**

**required result from mysql query is:**

```
SELECT J.journal_name,V.id,V.journal_id FROM journals AS J 
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
FROM volumes
WHERE id IN (
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM volumes
GROUP BY journal_id
)) AS V ON J.id = V.journal_id
```

**Now my try in laravel is:**

**controller is:**

```
public function index()
{
$volumes = volume::with('volumes')->orderBy('id','desc')->limit(1)->get();
    return view('welcome',compact('volumes'));
}
```

**volume model is:**

```
function volumes()
 {
      return $this->belongsTo(journal::class, 'journal_id');
 }
```

But it is giving only one row from entire volume table. I need last one row from each group of journal_id in volume table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HasOne` relationship:

```php
class Journal extends Model
{
    public function latestVolume()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Volume::class)->orderByDesc('id');
    }
}

$journals = Journal::with('latestVolume')->get();
```

Be aware that this will still fetch all volumes from the database. It then discards the "old" ones.

If you want to improve the performance by *really* only fetching the latest volume, you can use this package I've created: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

The package allows you to apply `limit()` to the relationship:

```php
class Journal extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

    public function latestVolume()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Volume::class)->orderByDesc('id')->limit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to define the models would be:

Journal model

```
function volumes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Volume::class);
}
```

Volume model

```
function journals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Journal::class);
}
```

Now `$journal->volumes` should return all the volumes that belong to that journal.