# Limiting an eager-loaded relationship to the latest result

Tags: eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-5.8

I have two models with a very simple `hasMany` relationship:

```php
// Location.php
public function forecasts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Forecast');
}

// Forecast.php

public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location');
}
```

Following the Laravel documentation on [constraining eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads), I want to get all `Location`s along with the latest `Forecast` belonging to that location, but I can't use the `limit()` method:

```php
// LocationsApiController.php

public function index()
{
    $locations = Location::with(['forecasts' => function ($query) {
        $query->latest()->limit(1); // LIMIT NOT ALLOWED
    }])->get();

    return response($locations->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

How do I build a query to get latest forecast for **each** location?

EDIT: It's possible to define a [separate `hasOne` Eloquent relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145389) between `Location` and `Forecast` (e.g. `latestForecast`) and doing the limit there.  (That Staudenmeir package looks very interesting too!)  However, this relationship would produce a "nonstandard" output in the JSON (ideally the JSON returned would be exactly the same structure as `Location::with('forecasts')->get();`, just with only one object in the forecasts array instead of multiple).  This allows the Vue components on the frontend to be highly reusable and not worry about what context they are being used in, they just render the data.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2111384/4468423) is asking much the same thing, but in regular sql.  will see if i can convert any of the answers to the query builder syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find only last row from second table, along with its first table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145389/how-to-find-only-last-row-from-second-table-along-with-its-first-table-row)

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir beautiful package you have there!  why is that not part of laravel core yet?  :)  but i still need to overcome the differences in the returned objects.  beginning to think that mangling the object after the fact might be the quickest way to go.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26035

Comment: Regarding the JSON structure: You can also apply the limit to a `HasMany` relationship.

Comment: my man!  much easier than mangling the json after the fact.